# My computer doesn't boot without a USB drive

Tags: grub2

I installed ubuntu onto a usb drive, but now the problem i face is that the computer doesn't boot without the USB inserted. It goes to grub rescue. I also have ubuntu installed on a partition on my hardisk (after installing it on the usb), i would like to direct the stage 1 grub to the stage to 2 on that. I'm pretty confused, and don't know much about ubuntu, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Can you boot the Ubuntu that's on the HDD? If yes, do it, open a terminal window, and run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`.

Answer (score 0):

Ow, this is a mess (lol) !

I'd suggest (I read that it doesn't concern a dualboot with Windows, or am I wrong on this? )

you follow the steps to take:

- make a bootable USB-stick with an Ubuntu-ISO of your wish (12.04.2 is a good option since it has for about 5 years support) ; you can do that on Windows or Ubuntu (startup disc -tool)
- Boot this USB-stick; an Ubuntu-logo should show followed with an option to try Ubuntu or Install Ubuntu
- Make a good working internet-connection (you can do that with wireless or cabled)
- Select install Ubuntu on the hard-drive (USB works but it's slow in respons; using Ubuntu on a hard disk is by far out the better option, unless you need a stick for travelling around. )
- follow the onscreen options and select 'use the entire disk' (mind you: if you have WIndows on your hard disk you should select Ubuntu side by side with Windows)
- Let the installer run and proceed with required info asked by the installer.
- When everything is finished , reboot and voila you have Ubuntu.

For having Ubuntu on a portable USB-drive, I'd suggest you make a new question here and we'll guide you all the way.

I hope this will lead you further, and if you [click here](https://help.ubuntu.com/) you'll have more information.